# MongoDB: How to measure latency or other parameters of DB

Tags: java, mongodb, latency

**Situation:** App has an API part and one of the API calls returns status of MongoDB. Right now it returns only "OK" or "DOWN".

```
final DB defaultDb = dbFactory.getDb(dbName);
```

Getting general status of DB from DB object is not a problem. But how I can get some more information? Like latency or other DB parameters? And is it possible to get more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the diagnostic commands in the reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/nav-diagnostic/

You can run any of those using `DB.command(String)` method.

**EDIT**: I have also found a `CommandResult DB.getStats()` method in the Java API.

Comment: DB.command(String) - that nice, there are a lot of stats what I can get. But also it can be good to get some info from MongoClient to see for exmpl for amount of of connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ELK stack. For e.g., look here:

https://logz.io/blog/mongodb-performance-monitoring-elk-stack/